# Failed to install apk on device (null)

Tags: android, null

I am stuck with my app project for quite a while now because of the error above in the title. I know there are many other topics about it and I have tried several solutions, but none seem to fix my problem.

What I have tried so far:

- Increased ADB connection time out (ms)
- Changed the environmental path variable suggested here: http://anandpandia.blogspot.nl/2011/01/failed-to-install-helloandroidapk-on.html
- Restarted my phone
- Changed install location to external at the manifest file

The problem seems to have something to do with the size of the app. It worked fine until I addes a few mp3 files. The app is now around 150MB I think. I do have plenty of space on both the internal disk and the SD.

Console output

```
[2013-11-09 14:47:47 - POapp] ------------------------------
[2013-11-09 14:47:47 - POapp] Android Launch!
[2013-11-09 14:47:47 - POapp] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-09 14:47:47 - POapp] Performing com.example.poapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-11-09 14:47:47 - POapp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device     compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-11-09 14:49:03 - POapp] Uploading POapp.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2013-11-09 14:49:39 - POapp] Installing POapp.apk...
[2013-11-09 14:51:40 - POapp] Failed to install POapp.apk on device '0123456789ABCDEF!
[2013-11-09 14:51:40 - POapp] (null)
[2013-11-09 14:51:40 - POapp] Launch canceled!
```

Logcat errors (after a second run):

```
11-09 15:08:07.697: E/VoldConnector(492): NDC Command {312 asec create smdl2tmp2 151 ext4 8b2b620d8895582cbbc8637606418f53 10016 1} took too long (49368ms)
11-09 15:09:30.360: E/GetJar SDK(707): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
11-09 15:09:30.360: E/GetJar SDK(707): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
11-09 15:09:30.360: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:121)
11-09 15:09:30.360: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:61)
11-09 15:09:30.360: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:86)
11-09 15:09:30.360: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
11-09 15:09:30.631: E/GetJar SDK(707): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
11-09 15:09:30.631: E/GetJar SDK(707): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
11-09 15:09:30.631: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:121)
11-09 15:09:30.631: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:61)
11-09 15:09:30.631: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:86)
11-09 15:09:30.631: E/GetJar SDK(707):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Comment: i am having the exact same problem with a 2GB apk

Comment: have you found the answer to this problem?
I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Have you cleaned the project yet? When adding new resources, the project must first be cleaned before it is rebuilt.

If you are using Eclipse, click Project -> Clean... and clean all projects.
If you are using command line, type "ant clean" in the project directory.

Now try rebuilding the project.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this before, without any luck. Forgot to list it.